# Force Windows use .EXE on PATH rather than CMD.EXE internal command

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, mkdir

When I execute a command with the same name as an internal command, instead of searching in the path Windows simply uses the one found in CMD.EXE.

For example, **MKDIR** is an internal command built into `CMD.EXE`. It does not support the same options as the Unix version (e.g. `-p` and `--help`). If I use these options Windows will simply create files named *-p* or *--help* even though I have the GNU version of **mkdir** installed in a directory in my path.

This becomes an issue when working with certain programs that use **mkdir** through the terminal. For example, the [gulpfile for prose](https://github.com/prose/prose/blob/master/gulpfile.js) contains three `mkdir -p` commands that, create a folder `-p` in the working directory and then throw errors. I have to manually edit the gulpfile such that it uses the installed **mkdir.exe**, which makes it harder for me to share my fork cross-platform.

How can I force the Windows shell to use the `mkdir.exe` found in PATH rather than CMD.EXE?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How can I force the Windows shell to use the mkdir.exe found in PATH rather than CMD.EXE?

Surround the executable name in double-quotes.  For example:

```
"MKDIR"
```

This forces Windows to look for your executable instead of running the internal command. If you have parameters that also require double-quotes, use this syntax:

```
"MKDIR" -firstParam "C:\foobar\long file name.ext"
```

Comment: Alternatively you should be able to specify the full path to the mkdir program you wish to call.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. What it does is it creates a new file named ".exe" in the current directory. @davidgo I can specify the whole path, but that becomes an issue with sharing my code with others: not everyone has mkdir located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\mkdir.exe`!

Comment: Surrounding in double quotes works! You don't even need to specify the extension -- just `"mkdir"`. Thanks!