# Why can't I override mkdir with Git for Windows's version?

Tags: windows, command-line, git

I've installed Git for Windows with the "overwrite native commands" option checked. I've checked my PATH:

```
C:\Users\Domenic>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\python2;C:\python2\Scripts;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\;C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin;C:\depot_tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Ruby21-x64\bin;C:\ProgramData\nodist\bin;C:\ruby200\bin;C:\Chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\kdiff3;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox;C:\Users\Domenic\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Domenic\Dropbox\PATH
```

(if you don't want to scroll that much, just note that `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` is first)

I've checked with `where`:

```
C:\Users\Domenic>where mkdir
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\mkdir.exe
```

And when I run that directly, it works great:

```
C:\Users\Domenic>"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\mkdir.exe" --help
Usage: /usr/bin/mkdir [OPTION]... DIRECTORY...
Create the DIRECTORY(ies), if they do not already exist.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -m, --mode=MODE   set file mode (as in chmod), not a=rwx - umask
(... etc ...)
```

However, when I try to run `mkdir` from the command line, it always goes back to Windows's built-in one:

```
C:\Users\Domenic>mkdir --help
A subdirectory or file --help already exists.

C:\Users\Domenic>mkdir /?
Creates a directory.

MKDIR [drive:]path
(... etc ...)
```

Why can't I override mkdir?

Windows 10, Git for Windows 2.7.3

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/856582/force-windows-use-exe-on-path-rather-than-cmd-exe-internal-command seems similar but does not explain *why*

Comment: Because cmd searches for built in commands before searching for external commands in the path. Surrounding the command with `"`s forces cmd to look in the path and ignore internal commands

Comment: See [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699) for lots more on how cmd parsing works.